# 'form.save(commit=True)' not saving to database

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to use a `ModelForm` to create a new model in my database. The thing is, it's not saving it to there when I call `form.save(commit=True)`.

I am using Elastic Beanstalk (the free tier) to host my website. I feel like this has something to do with the problem.

This is my `forms.py`:

```
from datetime import date
from .models import Itinerary

class CreateItinerary(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Itinerary
        exclude = ["sights"]
    
    destination = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    start = forms.DateField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}), initial=date.today)
    end = forms.DateField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'type': 'date'}))

class FindPlaces(forms.Form):
    types = ((1, "restaurants"), (2, "attractions"), (3, "parks"), 
            (4, "national parks"), (5, "clothing stores"), (6, "malls"), 
            (7, "department stores"), (8, "stadiums"))

    place_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=types)
```

This is my `views.py` file:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import *
from .forms import *

class createItinerary(generic.TemplateView):
    template = "itineraries/create.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return render(request, self.template, 
            {
                "form" : CreateItinerary(request.POST, request.FILES),
            })
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = CreateItinerary(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new = form.save(commit=True)

            return redirect("/sights/")

        else:
            form = CreateItinerary

        return render(request, self.template, 
            {
                "form" : form,
            })

def plan_redirect(request, id):
    return redirect("/plan/%s" % id, request)

class plan(generic.TemplateView):
    find_places_form_class = FindPlaces
    template = "itineraries\plan.html"

    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        object = get_object_or_404(Itinerary, pk=id)

        return render(request, self.template, 
            {
                "find_places_form" : self.find_places_form_class(),
                "object" : object,
                "trip_length" : object.get_trip_length(),
            })
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Did you try only using form.save? You're not using the new variable anyway

Comment: @JimmyFl0 So do I just need to call form.save(commit=True) to save the model?

Answer (score 0):

In `generic.TemplateView` you have only `GET` method to use. Try using the `generic.FormView` to implement this.

More Details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormView

I hope this will helpful.

Comment: I think your solution would work, but the thing is, I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk, so is it saving my models somewhere else?

Comment: There is noting to deal with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Django generic.TemplateView only support GET method. In your case, you're using modelForms so the best way to accomplishes this by using generic.FormView think I am clear.